# GDAL can i try to create a workflow?

Tags: gdal, windows, workflow, shell

When i try to compose a workflow im confused to the funcionality of that.

I want to create a workflow to execute commands gdal. what syntax I can use if I wanted to create a .bat file?

For example when i try to use this :

```
FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR "C:\FOLDER\*shp."') DO (
    SET infile =%%i
    SET outfile=!infile:.shp=.tif!
    gdal_rasterize -a x4031 -ts 1024 1024 -l %FOLDER%!infile! %FOLDER%!outfile!
)
```

I get some errors. (%%i was unexpected at this time)
 Whats the correct syntax?

Comment: I would recommend the Python GDAL/OGR API: https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/.

Comment: "I get some errors" is not helpful. Please edit your question to include the error message.

Comment: %%i was unexpected at this time

Comment: If you wish to stay in batch-files and not go into the API, try to not have a space between in 'infile =%%i', so that you have 'infile=%%i'.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you using Python OGR API for creating workflows.
Here is a [link](https://pythongisandstuff.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/installing-gdal-and-ogr-for-python-on-windows/) to a good tutorial how to install GDAL/Python etc on Windows. You will find tons of workflow examples in the internet.